# Howto forward DNS request for local zone to external DNS when not matched locally (BIND9)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a domain `example.com` and use Azure DNS to resolve all the hostnames that should be visible from the internet. I have defined `mail.example.com` to point to `198.51.100.123` and it can be resolved by external clients without any issue.

The `example.com` is also used on my LAN and use bind resolves all local IP addresses, which works fine for the local hostnames. My DHCP server also knows how to deal with this and updates the zone files properly. All DNS requests for other zones are forwarded to Cloudflare DNS.

I would like my server to use the local nameserver and if it cannot find an entry in the local zonefile, it should contact the Azure server and check it. When I add the following entries to my zone file, then it works for these hostnames:

```
external-dns            A       1.1.1.1
vpn                     NS      external-dns
www                     NS      external-dns
ftp                     NS      external-dns
```

Wildcards don't work in Bind9 anymore, so I cannot use `* NS external-dns`. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Split horizon dns is always a pita to maintain, AFAIK always a manual job and should be avoided like the plague. Note that you can always add internal records to your public dns zone as long as they don’t overlap with existing records. (and do away with the example.com zone in your internal dns server) The fact that `Ramons-desktop.example.com.` exists in your public dns zone and maps to an IP-address from one of the private use ranges such as 10.* or 192.168.* doesn’t break anything and is not a security issue.  Next time use a sub domain or different domain you own for internal use

Comment: @HermanB I have changed my internal domain to `int.example.com` and registered it with Azure DNS, so I can issue certificates for this domain that is only available locally. Using this domain also clearly indicates which hosts are internal and which ones can be used from the internet. Just needed another way of thinking. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `response-policy` zone instead of a master zone for `example.com`

When attempting to resolve a hostname, bind will look in the `response-policy` zone file first and if it does not find the answer it will continue looking.

Here's an example setup:

```
options {
    # Your normal options
    response-policy { zone "local_example_com"; };
};
zone "local_example_com" {
    type master;
    file "master/local_example.zone";
    allow-query {none;};
};
```

Then add a zone file called `master/local_example.zone` containing the following:

```
$TTL 24H
@    SOA LOCALHOST. named-mgr.example.com (1 1d 1h 30d 2h)
     NS  LOCALHOST.

host1.example.com     A   192.168.1.1
host2.example.com     A   192.168.1.2
host3.example.com     A   192.168.1.3
host4.example.com     A   192.168.1.4
```

When you try to resolve `host1.example.com` it will get the answer from the `response-policy` zone and when you try to resolve `mail.example.com` it will resolve it using `example.com` nameservers.

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard is not possible, so I decided to use a different approach:

1. All external sites are hosted on the `example.com` domain.
2. All internal sites are hosted on the `int.example.com` domain.

The `example.com` is not changed in any way and is still available in Azure DNS (like it always was). The internal Bind server now hosts the `int.example.com` domain and the DHCP server is also updated to push `int.example.com` as the local domain.

I want my internal sites to be available via HTTPS, so I need to be able to create certificates using LetsEncrypt for the `int.example.com` domain. LetsEncrypt cannot reach my internal services, so I have to revert to DNS verification.

I added the `int.example.com` zone as a child zone of `example.com` in Azure DNS. This zone won't have any DNS entries, because we use the local server for that. We don't want to expose any internal information to external DNS servers. Its sole purpose is DNS verification for LetsEncrypt, so AcmeSh should have the proper credentials to create/remove TXT records. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/How-to-use-Azure-DNS) to create the proper credentials. My setup is using Azure DNS, but it should work for any DNS that supports subzones.